# Save an image to the local folder from the website by clicking a link or button in mobile browser

Tags: html, mobile, web, onclick

How can I save an image from the webpage by clicking on a link in smart phone, using JavaScript, jQuery or using HTML controls?

The sample code is as follows:

```
<a href="">Save image</a> 
<!--The Link to save the image-->
<img src"../images/logo.png" alt="Logo" height="50" width="50" /> 
<!--The Image that I wanted to save-->`
```

Now, I want to save the image `logo.png` in my local folder, by clicking on the link in smart phones (iPhone 4+, Android 2.1+ and BlackBerry 6+)?

Answer (score 2):

Usually browsers have their own handling when you click a link which points directly to a downloadable file: either asks you where you want to save it, or it downloads the file to a predefined location. I'm not sure if you can override this.

Comment: Hi Cezar 

I need to put an anchor tag or input type='button' to prompt the user to save the image from the website. Apart from pressing the screen is their any other option to save the image?

Comment: Actually, usually the desktop browsers open the image in a new tab and then the user saves the image, but as far as I remember, the mobile browsers would prompt for download. You could also surround the <img> tag with the <a> tag so the user would tap the image for download. Another way beside the tap or tap & hold I don't know, if that's what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

For example, iOS shows you the prompt to save the file when you press and hold onto the image. I don't think that you could do that just like in a desktop browser, like httprequest or response.binarywrite (c#).

Comment: Hi Cezar and Eric

I need to put an anchor tag or input type='button' to prompt the user to save the image from the website. Apart from pressing the screen is their any other option to save the image?