# How can I create an Image Download Link in HTML for a Mobile Page?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, mobile, mobile-safari

I have a mobile html page which contains images. I want to create a button or a link which is used for a download of an image. The image should then be saved to the users mobile image gallery.

I have seen this post: [How can I create download link in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793751/how-can-i-create-download-link-in-html)

The solution

```
<a href="link/to/your/download/file" download="filename">Download link</a>
```

is working in desktop browsers but not on mobile.

Here is a JSFiddle I made: http://jsfiddle.net/tDVqH/4/

Note: The image is created in the browser i.e., in a HTML5 canvas element. This image can be generated with canvas.toDataUrl(). The resulting image should be saved to the mobile image gallery.

**How can save an image to the users mobile image gallery with a click/tap? Is there a JavaScript solution without the ser round trip with a unknown header?**

Edit: I also found the following questions but they do not have an answer. [Save an image to the local folder from the website by clicking a link or button in mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130258/save-an-image-to-the-local-folder-from-the-website-by-clicking-a-link-or-buton-i?rq=1) and [Save an image to a mobile phone gallery from a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17749145/save-an-image-to-a-mobile-phone-gallery-from-a-browser)

Comment: This may work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124064/force-browsers-to-download-a-file-rather-than-open

Comment: This may work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124064/force-browsers-to-download-a-file-rather-than-open

or this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461535/how-to-force-a-file-to-download-using-php-on-mobile-browsers

Comment: Not it is not working on iOS.

Comment: HTML5 download attribute wont work with Safari, you should find any alternative.

Comment: @Manu that is why I ask this question!

Comment: I guess you are building an awesome image editor for mobiles, that allows users to save their work to their mobile. The `mobile browsers` are not ready for it yet, since there is no secure way for a web app to interact and access the file systems of the mobile. HTML5 File API has come a long way, and even longer way left. Even if there is a hack, it ll probably leave you the worse since it may not work cross-mobile. My best bet would be to go for a cross-platform tool that fits the bill. Just my two cents.

Comment: have you get something working ? If yes please let me know as I am also stuck with the same issue. @confile

Answer (score 4):

Somebody seems to have [answered this already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16302092/1079817),

> ```
> <a href="/path/to/image" download="ImageName" title="ImageName">
>     <img src="/path/to/image" alt="ImageName">
> </a> It's not yet fully supported http://caniuse.com/#feat=download, but you can use with modernizr
> ```
>
> http://modernizr.com/download/#-a_download (under Non-core detects) to
>   support all browsers.

Have not tested, but should work in mobiles as well.

I would add that, as a server side solution, you could also add Response Headers to your download endpoint by

- Setting it up in apache (.htaccess) / nginx configuration
- Right from the code

Answer (score 1):

Support for download attribute: http://caniuse.com/download

You can set headers on the server, if that's an option for you.  The HTTP header you want to send is Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="imagename.jpg".

Differs depending on your server..

In Node/Express:

```
// only on imgs
function(req, res){
    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=imagename.jpg');
}
```

In the HTML:

```
<a href="imagename.jpg">Download link</a>
```

Server will send Content-Disposition header when it gets the request for the file and force browsers to download.

Comment: But how can I download the image on mobile browsers with your solution?

Comment: But what if you create the image in the browser, e.g., when you convert a canvas to an image?

Answer (score 1):

Use html5 download attribute as solution above by @theunexpected1. For browsers that don't support it, remove A tag to force user to right click or long touch to download

```
<script>
var downloadAttrSupported = ("download" in document.createElement("a"))
if (!downloadAttrSupported){
   $('img.media').unwrap();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

The force-download for files usually opened by the browser can be done with the .htaccess file in the directory where your images are.

It was replied previously here:

[Force a file or image to download using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218466/force-fileimage-download-with-htaccess)

I haven't tested so don't know if it will work with mobile browsers though.