# Can I programmatically save an image from a URL to a gallery on iOS 13?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, instagram, progressive-web-apps, ios13

I have a react PWA application, it has functionality in order to post the image to Instagram story. To do this, the image is saved in the gallery and Instagram picks it up. Is it possible to implement such functionality on iOS13?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22338201/how-can-i-create-an-image-download-link-in-html-for-a-mobile-page

Comment: @gilbert-v the solutions that are provided there do not work. Thanks